# How to set a max length for the search input in (AngularJS) ui-select component?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, ui-select

Suppose I have the following (very basic) code for a [ui-select](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select)

```
<ui-select ng-model="vm.selected">
    <ui-select-match>
        <span ng-bind="$select.selected.label"></span>
    </ui-select-match>
    <ui-select-choices repeat="item in vm.items">
        <span ng-bind="item.label"></span>
    </ui-select-choices>
</ui-select>
```

Now, this generates all the html nodes, etc, which contain an input for searching and filtering the options displayed on the list.

The **problem** is:

How to set (in any variant) a maximum length for the input search ?

The **directive doesn't offer** any built-in data-attribute for doing so.

So, the expected behavior is: If I set a max length of 10 characters, when the user type/copy+paste a string larger than the specified length, the string in the input search, gets truncated (though, if you could provide me with some other solution which allows the user to input only certain numbers of characters in the input search, I would really appreciated)

I found [this related question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33216113/how-to-set-max-length-for-ui-select-match), but it's not applicable for this case, since I have no way to access to the value which is being typed on the input search via an `ng-model` or similar.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can add a custom attribute directive to the `ui-select` directive, then search for the `input.ui-select-search` inside it, and finally add and HTML `maxlength` attribute... ([PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/9FNoAPWkRiatkJWeX3cs?p=preview))

**HTML**

```
<ui-select ng-model="vm.selected" maxlen="15">
    <ui-select-match>
        <span ng-bind="$select.selected.label"></span>
    </ui-select-match>
    <ui-select-choices repeat="item in vm.items">
        <span ng-bind="item.label"></span>
    </ui-select-choices>
</ui-select>
```

**DIRECTIVE**

```
app.directive('maxlen', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attr) {
      var $uiSelect = angular.element(element[0].querySelector('.ui-select-search'));
      $uiSelect.attr("maxlength", attr.maxlen);
    }
  }
});
```

*Probably it isn't the best solution, but as you say if `ui-select` doesn't support it, you have to do it by yourself...*

Comment: Thanks for your solution! I was thinking in something less dramatic than creating a new directive, but given the current state of the _ui-select_ this is fine.